# How to split a string containing time into parts in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a file which contains lines of 2 different times and looks like this:

```
01:31:51,210 --> 01:31:54,893
```

The format is `hours:minutes:seconds,milliseconds`.  My question is how to split these two times into two arrays.  `line.split(':', ',')` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'time'
s = '01:31:51,210 --> 01:31:54,893'
a = s.split(' --> ') # => ["01:31:51,210", "01:31:54,893"]
b1 = a.map{|a1| a1.split(/[:,]/)} # => [["01", "31", "51", "210"], ["01", "31", "54", "893"]]
```

Or, you can parse directly into `Time` objects

```
b2 = a.map{|a1| Time.parse(a1)} # => [2013-06-05 01:31:51 +0400, 2013-06-05 01:31:54 +0400]
```

Comment: `Time.parse`, that's whose concern problems like this one are.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: this time range looks like it's part of some subtitle format. So maybe he doesn't need full-blown `Time` instances. Who knows?

Comment: No, Time is fine...I just wasn't aware there was a Time class.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Split once, then split again on the results (with a regex):
`line.split(" --> ").map { |l| l.split(/[:,]/) }`